# Storybook + Vue3 - Error when trying to use custom directives

Tags: vuejs3, storybook, vue-directives

When trying to use custom directives with Vue3 and storybook, I get this error:

[image: Error with Vue3 directive in storybook]

I don't understand the issue and have no idea where to even start to look. I'm still very new to Vue and storybook.
I created a small test directive just to make sure it wasn't something to do with a more complicated one:

```
app.directive('red-bg', {
  beforeMount: (element, binding) => {
    element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
});
```

and applied it:
`<div class="wmr-select relative" ref="selectRef" v-red-bg>`

It works in the normal app part of the the project (as you can see with the red bg):
[image]

But in story book I get the error in the first image.
I haven't been able to find any kind of answer for this.

Hoping someone will swoop in and save me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### For Storybook 7+, see [P-A Bouly's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76530860/5784924)

Since Storybook is using another file to initialize your app, you need to define the directive in both files.

This is explained in the [configuring storybook](https://storybook.js.org/docs/vue/configure/overview#configure-story-rendering) section of the doc.

In my case, I had defined the directive in my `main.js` file, but I also had to define it in the `preview.js` file, of the `.storybook` folder.

As a reference, here is was my `.storybook/preview.js` looks like:

```js
import { app } from "@storybook/vue3";
/* all the other import needed for my project **/
import store from "@/store";
/** ...  */

export const parameters = {
   /** Some parameters specifics to the plugins of storybook. **/
   /** For example, when using themes. **/
};

/** App specific initialization, ex defining locale  */
const i18n = createI18n({
  locale: "en",
  fallbackLocale: "en",
  messages: myLocaleMessageLoader()
});

/** registering directives  */
app.directive("my-custom-directive", myCustomDirectiveHandler);

app
  .use(i18n)
  .use(store)
  /** all the other `.use` that my app need.*/
```

Please note the usage of storybook own `app` in the import.

After adding the directive in the `.storybook/preview.js` I was successfully able to use it in my stories.

Comment: Thanks, will try this out and get back to the post with the results.

Answer (score 3):

For storybook 7, as mentioned in the migration guide [here](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/MIGRATION.md#vue3-replaced-app-export-with-setup), **app** is not exported anymore from "@storybook/vue3" but now you have access to the **setup** function.

So now to add a directive or a global component you will have to :

```
import { setup } from '@storybook/vue3';
import Button from './Button.vue';
import myCustomDirectiveHandler from './myCustomDirectiveHandler.ts';

setup((app) => {
  app.component('GlobalButton', Button);
  app.directive("my-custom-directive", myCustomDirectiveHandler);
});
```